# Cannot access Huawei Router web interface from Xiaomi Router

Tags: networking, router

I have a 4G LTE Huawei router (WIFI not working) and its default web interface login IP is 192.168.1.1 and it automatically redirect to **homerouter.cpe**. I am using Xiaomi Redmi AX3000 router as WIFI access point and has connected the huawei router's LAN port to xiaomi's WAN port. Xiaomi's web interface IP is 192.168.31.1 . Internet is working without a problem. But I cannot access huawei's WEB UI using 192.168.1.1 when connected via xiaomi access point.  because it redirect to domain **homerouter.cpe** and getting This site can't be reached error.

[image]

Comment: Try accessing via an Ethernet connection. More likely to work.

Comment: It's a DNS lookup issue. You can access to internet because it's public DNS names, but for `homerouter.cpe` it's an internal name configured inside the `4G LTE Huawei` router. You should change your DNS server inside your OS. It looks like you are using the DNS of your `Xiaomi Redmi` device.